# SQL sum multiple fields with conditions

Tags: sql

I'm gonna to make a SUM function with these columns of Profile table when each column is greater than 1.
How can I do it?

```
bank         docs          personal
2              1             2
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following *counts* the rows where the values are greater than 1:

```
select sum(case when bank > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as bank,
       sum(case when docs > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as docs,
       sum(case when personal > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as personal
from Profile;
```

The following counts the number of columns within a row with values greater than 1:

```
select p.*,
       (case when bank > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when docs > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when personal > 1 then 1 else 0 end
       ) as cnt
from Profile p;
```

These are the two most sensible interpretations of our question.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of rows where each column value is greater than one:

```
select sum(bank + docs + personal)
from Profile
where bank > 1 and docs > 1 and personal > 1
;
```

> ```
> with t as (
>     select           0 as v0, 1 as v1 from dual
>     union all select 3 as v0, 2 as v1 from dual
>     )
>
> select sum(v0 + v1)
> from t
> where v0 > 1 and v1 > 1
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUM(V0+V1) |
> | ---------: |
> |          5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ea83b0f59edbb623d2c6c7ecd1d1a0db)*

Answer (score 0):

The sum of each individual column when the column is greater than 1:   (untested)

```
select sum(case when isnull(bank,0) > 1 then bank else 0 end) banktotal
      ,sum(case when isnull(docs,0) > 1 then docs else 0 end) docstotal
      ,sum(case when isnull(personal,0) > 1 then personal else 0 end) personaltotal
from Profile
```

isnull() may or may not be needed based on your data and table design.